# Newest version of HomeBrew, versions no longer supported

Tags: homebrew

I am having problems installing the old version of grails on my mac, with homebrew.

The spot where I get stuck is at the `brew versions grails` as it will say that versions is no longer used.
I have executed `brew tap homebrew/versions` but the versions command do still not work.
How in the newest version of brew can I install Grails 2.3.5?

```
Error: The `versions` command is no longer supported.
You can use the homebrew-versions tap instead:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions
Or use `brew log` to browse the git history.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
```

then:

```
brew install homebrew/versions/grails23
```

`brew search grails` will show you all the available ones to install.

Comment: grails23 is not 2.3.5

Comment: I `brew search python` but don't get minor versions of Python. I'm trying to get 2.7.9 or later!

Comment: `brew search grails` returns only 2 entries for me:
`grails   homebrew/versions/grails25`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be very easy as of right now:

```
user@MacBook-Pro:~/% brew search grails        
grails ✔                                                                                                         grails@2.5
user@MacBook-Pro:~/% brew install grails@2.5
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for uncrustify. It does not find old formulas.